# Converting Excel data to Json in a particular format using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, excel, data-manipulation

I have an excel file which contains some data.

Example data:

```
intent          examples            output
Greeting        Hi                  Welcome 
Greeting        Hello               Welcome 
Greeting        How are you         Welcome
Goodbye         bye                 Goodbye 
Goodbye         take care           Take care
```

I want to read the excel file and then convert this data to a particular JSON format of the following form using Node.JS.

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Greeting",
      "examples": [
        {
          "text": "Hi"
        },
        {
          "text": "Hello"
        },
        {
          "text": "How are you"
        }
      ],
      "description": "All greeting messages"
    }
  ],
  "dialog_nodes": [
    {
      "title": "Greeting",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "text": "Welcome"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Goodbye",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "text": "bye"
              },
              {
                "text": "Take care"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Logic applied is first Group by on 'intent' and then Find unique 'Output'  for each unique 'intent'

If we have a base json of the following format, i just want to append it such that it looks like above:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "intents": [
      ],
  "dialog_nodes": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "",
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

}

I am very new to Node.JS and its libraries. Would anyone please be able to help me on this problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

An example of how to use it would be:

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

function readXls(path) {
  let values = [];
  try {
    let wb = null;
    wb = XLSX.readFile(buffer);

    let ws = wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];

    let range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"]).e.r;

    if (range) {
      let rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
        header: "A",
        raw: false,
        range: `A1:ZZ${range+1}`,
        dateNF: "YYYY-MM-DD"
      });

      // here you can compute each row

      return rows
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```